# How to pass pdf file from one page to another page within same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Webpage1 has a button to create crystal report and it saves .pdf file to local

Now I need to create the .pdf and pass  this file to webpage2 as attached under gridview.

Anybody got some idea let me know !

Comment: You can't pass the file itself between pages (and anyway that would be very inefficient), but if the file is stored on the server, then on the second page you could provide a _link_ to it

Comment: Thanks for reply Adyson .